# Check wether a set of data already exists in current worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image: this is how the table where I have to search for the data would look like but filled with lots of data] [image: That's the table items I am searching for. I'm looking for the data in this exact order so the whole block of data]I have a large table filled with data. What I want to do is check wether a set of data already exists within this table. I have inserted the data I am looking for in a separate worksheet. The Range with the table items I am looking for I called "SearchedData" and the Area where I am checking wether it holds the data I am looking for I called "SearchArea".

My code only shows me the data would exist but in the worksheet I am working on it doesn't so there must be something wrong with my code. Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

```
Sub CheckWetherDataExists()

    Dim SearchedData As Variant
    Dim SearchArea As Variant

    SearchedData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("C5:G8").Value
    SearchArea = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A:E").Value

    If SearchArea = SearchedData Then
    MsgBox ("Searched Data already exists")

    Else: MsgBox ("Searched Data is missing")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Simply use `match()` formula to check. If match formula return any number then data is exist otherwise it will give you error.

Comment: `Range("C5:G8").Value` will result in an array of values but you cannt compare arrays like `SearchArea = SearchedData` you must loop. Also your ranges are different in size so you cannot compare them directly. What is the aim of this? Do you want to check if the **complete** data range `C5:G8` exists **anywhere** in columns `A:E`? Or do you want to check each cell on it's own? Please be more specific here or give a screenshot for explanation.

Comment: @Harun24HR `match` would not work with a range as criteria. Not that simple.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ excacrly, I want to check wether the complete data in range(C5:G8) in worksheet "Tabelle2" exists in the table in worksheet "Tabelle1"

Comment: and yes if it exists anywhere in the worksheet "Tabelle1". "Tabelle1" contains a large amount of data and what I want to do is checking wether a certain piece of the table already exists somewhere in this table.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes, I am looking wether the table items in the exact order of range(C5:G8)  exist.

Comment: Use a table of matches to check each individual cell in the range.. if just one is an error then the data is not identical...

Comment: I just added screenshots of an exemplary table to clearify what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way more complicated to solve.

Imagine `Tabelle2` as following:

[image]

And `Tabelle1` as following:

[image]

I suggest to use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) to find the first occurenc of the first cells data here this is represented by `11`. And then check if the rest of the data is right/below there too. Do this in a loop until all occurences are checked.

So in `Tabelle1` the yellow areas will be ckecked but the only full match is at `A14:E17` which will be considered as duplicate.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckIfDataExists()
    Dim wsSearch As Worksheet
    Set wsSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Set SearchRange = wsSearch.Range("A1", wsSearch.Cells(wsSearch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    Dim SearchData() As Variant 'data array
    SearchData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("C5:G8").Value

    Dim FoundData() As Variant

    'remember first find to prevent endless loop
    Dim FirstFoundAt As Range
    Set FirstFoundAt = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchData(1, 1), After:=SearchRange.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not FirstFoundAt Is Nothing Then
        Dim FoundAt As Range
        Set FoundAt = FirstFoundAt
        Do
            Set FoundAt = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchData(1, 1), After:=FoundAt, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then
                FoundAt.Resize(UBound(SearchData, 1), UBound(SearchData, 2)).Select
                FoundData = FoundAt.Resize(UBound(SearchData, 1), UBound(SearchData, 2)).Value
                If AreArraysEqual(SearchData, FoundData) Then
                    MsgBox "data found at " & FoundAt.Resize(UBound(SearchData, 1), UBound(SearchData, 2)).Address
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Loop Until FoundAt Is Nothing Or FirstFoundAt.Row >= FoundAt.Row
    End If

    MsgBox "data not found"
End Sub

Private Function AreArraysEqual(Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long

    'default
    AreArraysEqual = True

    For iRow = LBound(Arr1, 1) To UBound(Arr1, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(Arr1, 2) To UBound(Arr1, 2)
            If Arr1(iRow, iCol) <> Arr2(iRow, iCol) Then
                AreArraysEqual = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code will do what you want reasonably fast.

```
Sub CheckWetherDataExists()

    Dim SearchedData As Variant
    Dim SearchArea As Variant
    Dim LookFor() As String
    Dim LookIn() As String
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    SearchedData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("C5:G8").Value
    LookFor = MergedRows(SearchedData)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        SearchArea = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    LookIn = MergedRows(SearchArea)

    For R = 1 To UBound(LookIn)
        If LookIn(R) = LookFor(1) Then
            If R < UBound(LookIn) - 2 Then
                For C = 2 To UBound(LookFor)
                    If LookIn(R + C - 1) <> LookFor(C) Then Exit For
                Next C
                If C > UBound(LookFor) Then
                    MsgBox "Match found in Row " & R
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next R
End Sub

Private Function MergedRows(RngVal As Variant) As String()

    Dim Fun() As String
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    ReDim Fun(1 To UBound(RngVal))

    For R = 1 To UBound(RngVal)
        For C = 1 To UBound(RngVal, 2)
            Fun(R) = Fun(R) & "," & RngVal(R, C)
        Next C
    Next R
    MergedRows = Fun
End Function
```

The code creates merged strings of 5 cells of both the SearchedData and the SearchArea data. This job is done by the Function *MergedRows*. In the process the SearchedData turn into array LookFor(1 To 3) and LookIn(1 To LastRow). Next the first element (representing a row) of LookFor is compared to each element (representing a row) of LookIn. If a match is found the other two rows are also compared. When all three elements (rows) match a message is issued and the search is terminated.

Comment: Thank you. But this code doesn't do anything. I have inserted the data I was searching for in the worksheet that the macro runs on (Tabelle1) but it doesn't show the Messagebox that indicated that the data was found..

Comment: My code was tested and worked. In order to test it on your data one would have to step through the code line by line (F8) and check why it fails. Toward this end I have added a description of the code's action to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!